# Can I clone a jupyterhub kernel?

Tags: pyspark, jupyter, jupyterhub, jupyter-kernel

I access a JupyterHub instance with some preconfigured kernels. I know how to create a new kernel from scratch, but how can I clone an existing one?  I want to customize it with my own packages.

I created a pure python kernel, but I'd like to clone our default spark kernel. The new kernel should have the *spark* object already created.

The JupyterHub env was set up by an admin. It uses pure Python (no Conda).

Comment: Is this a conda environment? Or how is the environment set up?

Comment: It is pure python and pyspark

Comment: Sorry I mean how was python and spark installed?

Comment: I don't know how they are installed. They were not installed using apt-get or yum

Comment: ok. I don't know how we can help with this sorry.

Comment: does `pip freeze` do the trick?